# Allow to run a python script but not allow to read its content

Tags: ubuntu, acl, access-control, account-restrictions

I want to demonstrate a client how my python script works on my server to which I'll give him access. Also, I don't want him to be able to see the code of the python script, only run it. Is it possible to do somehow by a means of Linux? Maybe by creating an additional user?

Comment: This is impossible unless you compile the Python script into an executable binary file.  As an interpreted script, the user must have access to read the script to be able to run it.  Google for "compile python on linux"; sorry I don't have the specific answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/261638/4464570

Answer (score 2):

So, in general, the answer to this sort of question is "no, not easily", but for your specific case I think you might actually be able to come up with a solution.

Assume that your client will be logging into your server as user `alice`.  Create another user `bob` that owns the script, and make it only readable/executable by user `bob`:

```
# chown bob /path/to/myscript
# chmod 700 /path/to/myscript
```

Now, create a `sudo` configuration that allows `alice` to run that one script as user `bob`.  For example, create `/etc/sudoers.d/alice` with the following configuration:

```
alice ALL=(bob) NOPASSWD:/path/to/myscript
```

Now:

- Your client logs in as `alice`.  `alice` is unable to read or execute the given script.
- `alice` can run the script by running `sudo -u bob /path/to/myscript`.  This will run script as user `bob`.

This solution has certain limitations: for example, because the script will be running as different user than the caller, you may have issues creating files in the caller's home directory.